# Adding a user_id to a Message model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, userid

I currently have a simple app that includes user authentication through devise and a message model(the message model uses Jquery and Faye). Both are working fine independently, but I would like to add a user_id to the messages.

I have already updated the schema and models with the relationship, but I am having trouble inputting the necessary code to have the view and controller input the relationship into the db, while keeping the jquery working. I wasn't sure of the best way, but here I tried to create a hidden field that would pull the user_id, not sure if this is even possible. Here is the applicable code, any help is appreciated.

Message index.html.erb

```
<ul id="chat">
  <%= render @messages %>
</ul>

<%= form_for Message.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.text_field :content %>
</div>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
</div>  
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit "Send" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb for messages

```
 <% broadcast "/messages" do %>
 $("#chat").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@user.message) %>");
 <% end %>
 $("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

Messages Controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   if @authentications = current_user
    @messages = Message.all
   else
    redirect_to authentications_url
    flash[:notice] = "You need to sign in before answering questions"
   end
  end

 def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @message = @user.message.create(params[:message])
 end
end
```

I think you have everything you would need, but if not, let me know and I will be happy to provide it for you.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two things to correct,

1)use user association to create message instance in form(probably current_user if logged-in user create a message)

```
<%= form_for user.messages.new, :remote => true do |f| %> #// assuming its has many association
```

2) if it is has_many association then change association in create action

```
@message = @user.messages.create(params[:message])
```

Comment: Thanks, so for 1) I made it current_user.messages.new since they are logged in and for 2) it does has_many so I made that change as well. The problem now is that the messages aren't being submitted, I am getting a 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:12:in `create' error on the server.

Comment: this is because, the params[:user_id] is nil use  params[:message][:user_id]. or you can try to create message using Message.create(params[:message]), this should work because message have user_id in it

Comment: I also, don't entirely understand why adding the message param before the user_id stops the nil error, so if anyone is up to it, I would love an explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when we use form_for object, then all form data comes in params[:object] and if you want to access a single attr like object.user_id you need to do params[:object][:user_id]. For more try to inspect the params using "p params" you sill find message as a hash which have the user_id.